# CLOSED -React: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'variable name' before initialization- Using [React Hook]

Tags: reactjs, api, multidimensional-array, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm very new to `React`. I'm trying to create a table that contains an array of data and the data to display is using the `set` method to retrieve the specific values from the multi-dimensional array. I'm using the `useState` and `Axios` for calling the API. I've also imported a component called `'material-table'` for the tablet UI. However, I'm getting an error message says "**ReferenceError: Cannot access 'finalprice' before initialization**" whenever trying to display the variable from the array

Here are my 2 main JS files.
CallAPI.js is the function file mainly to retrieve the API data.
Mtable.js is the component table to import the data from the API file and insert it into the material table.

CallAPI.js file:

```
 import Axios from "axios";
 import React, { useState, Component } from "react";
 import { StyleSheet, TextInput, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
 import './ButtonLogs.css';


class ComponentMain extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>

        </div>
    )

  }

}

function CallAPI () { 

const [DPID, setText] = useState('');
const [Quote, setText1] = useState('');

let gcmpapi =
  "https://blablabla/"+ DPID +"/blablabla"; // declare a variable to store the URL

const [finalprice,setGCMP1] = useState({
  id: 1,
  title: 'Final Price',
  Quote: '999999',
  SalesOrder: '999999',
  GCMP: finalprice, // <===== this is where cause the page throwing the error message.
    },) // declare a variable to store the array
      
   const callgcmpapi = () => { //assign a variable for a call function
           Axios.get (gcmpapi).then(
             (response) => {
             console.log(response);
             setGCMP1(response.data.Data.PurchaseSummary.PriceSummary.FinalPrice); // call the value from the multi-dimensional array
                  })
              };
        
      return ( 

    (<div className='MainButton'>
        <button class="button button1"onClick={() =>{
            callgcmpapi()
          }}>Extract API results</button>
        </div>
    );
    }

export {CallAPI};
export default ComponentMain;
```

MTable.js file:

```
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import { CallAPI } from "./CallAPI";

const MTable = () => {
    //...
  
  const columns = [
    { title: 'GCMP (DPID)', field: 'GCMP' }
  ];

  return (
    <div style={
      { maxWidth: '100%' }}>
      <MaterialTable columns={columns} data={CallAPI} title='Endpoints Directory' />
    </div>
  );

};

  export default MTable;
```

Error message:
[ReferenceError: Cannot access 'finalprice' before initialization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIaSg.png)

Comment: You're trying to use the value of `finalprice` to set the value of `finalprice`.  When you create that object, what value do you expect the `GCMP` property to have and why?  What value should it have?

Comment: Hi @David, I'm trying to carry the value `finalprice` from the dimensional array that had been set to `setGCMP1` and declare it to the `GCMP` in the array. Any advice I can proceed with this? my expectation output of the GCMP: 12345 <-- data from the `setGCMP1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doin it wrongly, you have to initializes with some value, separate out two dependent states,
you are doing wrongly that declare with itself initialized with itself and declared

```
const [DPID, setText] = useState('');
const [Quote, setText1] = useState('');

const [finalprice,setFinalprice] = useState("YOUR FINAL PRICE")

const [GCMP1,setGCMP1] = useState({
  id: 1,
  title: 'Final Price',
  Quote: '999999',
  SalesOrder: '999999',
  GCMP: finalprice, 
    }) 

let gcmpapi =
  "https://blablabla/"+ DPID +"/blablabla"; // declare a variable to store the URL
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashish, still having issues here. the value I wanted to display for the `GCMP` is from the `setGCMP1`  as it's getting the data from the multi-dimensional array of the API. What is the exact correct way of declaring two dependent states? I do not understand about the `useState("YOUR FINAL PRICE")` and `setFinalprice` you had share is not being used.